# Xcode 7 - Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch

Tags: ios, objective-c

My app keeps crashing on launch with this error:

```
Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
```

Here is where the error occurs:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    @autoreleasepool {
        int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

Here is my AppDelegate:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class LibraryDemoViewController;

@interface LibraryDemoAppDelegate : NSObject {
    UIWindow *window;
    UIViewController *viewController;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIViewController *viewController;

@end


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after app launch
    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return TRUE;

}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Override point for customization after app launch    
    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Why does this error happen and how do I fix it? This app demo came with no xib files or storeyboards

Comment: `window.rootViewController = viewController` instead of `addSubview` but since i dont see any initialization, it will probably be black.

Comment: Please [search for errors](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+Application+windows+are+expected+to+have+a+root+view+controller+at+the+end+of+application+launch) before posting.

Comment: BTW - the code you posted indicates that you are following a really old and outdate tutorial. Find an up-to-date one.